# Efficiently find at least one lattice point on hyperbola of equation $axy+bx+cy+d=0$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, diophantine-equations, hyperbolic-geometry, lattices, diophantine-geometry

I need an algorithm to efficiently find at least one lattice point on a hyperbola of equation $axy+bx+cy+d=0$.

Lattice point means integer coordinates and equation with integer means diophantine equations. The most closely related resources I've found are [Methods to solve quadratic Diophantine equations](https://www.alpertron.com.ar/METHODS.HTM#Ellipse) and [Integer solution to an hyperbola equation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1858701/integer-solution-to-an-hyperbola-equation), but the former looks for solutions of equations and the latter is asking something linked but different.

So, is there an algorithm (better if efficient of course), or is this an unsolved/open problem?

Comment: The equation is equivalent to $(ax+c)(ay+b)=bc-ad$, so you need to find a divisor of  $bc-ad$ which is $\equiv c\pmod a$ (if it exists).

Comment: If you can eifficiently find a lattice point on $xy-n=0$ (other than $(1,n)$ and variants), then you are on to a winner.